# Is "msg.sender.token1().gas(msg.gas)" too low-level call?

Tags: delegatecall, send, static-call, decompilers

***Context*** :

I decompiled this contract(https://bscscan.com/address/0x5cb11ce550a2e6c24ebfc8df86c5757b596e69c1#code) which is the attacker's smartcontract that hacked MEV-bot. You can check the transaction here(https://bscscan.com/tx/0xd48758ef48d113b78a09f7b8c7cd663ad79e9965852e872fdfc92234c3e598d2). I used dedaub to decompile the bytecode of the contract.

Here are some questions.

1. Is `msg.sender.token1().gas(msg.gas)` a low level call? (Because I heard It returns bool and bytes memory)
2. If it is, as far as I know `send`, `call`, `delegatecall`, `staticcall` are low level call. Here is where I feel confused. In `msg.sender.token1().gas(msg.gas)`, there are no examples I mentioned. What am I missing?

```js
// Decompiled by library.dedaub.com
// 2022.12.25 02:52 UTC

// Data structures and variables inferred from the use of storage instructions
address owner; // STORAGE[0x0] bytes 0 to 19


function 0x10a(uint256 varg0, uint256 varg1, uint256 varg2) private { 
    require(varg0.data + varg0.length - varg0.data >= 96);
    require(MEM[varg0.data] == address(MEM[varg0.data]));
    v0 = v1 = varg0[64];
    if (0 == varg2) {
        v2, v3 = msg.sender.token1().gas(msg.gas);
        require(v2); // checks call status, propagates error data on error
        require(MEM[64] + RETURNDATASIZE() - MEM[64] >= 32);
        require(v3 == address(v3));
        goto 0x214;
    } else {
        v4, v3 = msg.sender.token0().gas(msg.gas);
        require(v4); // checks call status, propagates error data on error
        require(MEM[64] + RETURNDATASIZE() - MEM[64] >= 32);
        require(v3 == address(v3));
    }
    ...
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

token0()/token1() are functions of the uniswap v2 pair contract. I believe those are just normal calls, and the checks are just introduced by the compiler.

Comment: The decompiled version is really difficult to understand. Is there any tool or something to make it easier to read?

Comment: No. You can try other decompilers like https://ethervm.io/decompile or https://etherscan.io/bytecode-decompiler to see if you prefer their output, but it won't get any better than that.